# Preview Documents in Android

Tags: android

Hi does android have a native document preview window like iOS? i'm creating an app that handles documents and know iOs has a default document preview Window. I'm wanting to if it android has the same or would i be better just downloading the document and having the user preview the document in there chosen app. ideally and like to keep the user in my app rather than go to another but if its not standard android then i will accommodate that.

Does anyone know the best way to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no "native document preview" but you dont need to bother much. Just fire proper `Intent` to do the preview and let other apps do the job (do not forget to handle "there's no app to handle this intent" case correctly and warn your user (and perhaps suggest installing some apps to have this "fixed")).